# svg package not rendering svg containing math

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, unicode-math, input-encodings, svg

I have an svg file of an equation as follows

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:wrs="http://www.wiris.com/xml/cvs-extension" height="29" width="85" wrs:baseline="20"><!--MathML: <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mi mathvariant="script">l</mi><msqrt><mpadded lspace="-4px"><mn>8</mn><mi>&#x3C0;</mi><msub><mi>&#x3B5;</mi><mn>0</mn></msub><mi>m</mi><mi>g</mi></mpadded></msqrt></math>--><defs><style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'math1437d7d1d97917cd627a34a6a0f';src:url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,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)format('truetype');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}@font-face{font-family:'scriptdf906bde6d2bb9848a5f23b35';src:url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,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)format('truetype');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}</style></defs><text font-family="scriptdf906bde6d2bb9848a5f23b35" font-size="16" text-anchor="middle" x="4.5" y="20">&#x1D4C1;</text><polyline fill="none" points="12,-22 11,-22 5,0 2,-9" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(9.5,26.5)"/><polyline fill="none" points="5,0 2,-9 0,-8" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(9.5,26.5)"/><line stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="1" x1="21.5" x2="83.5" y1="4.5" y2="4.5"/><text font-family="Arial" font-size="16" text-anchor="middle" x="23.5" y="20">8</text><text font-family="math1437d7d1d97917cd627a34a6a0f" font-size="16" font-style="italic" text-anchor="middle" x="34.5" y="20">&#x3C0;</text><text font-family="Arial" font-size="16" font-style="italic" text-anchor="middle" x="43.5" y="20">&#x3B5;</text><text font-family="Arial" font-size="12" text-anchor="middle" x="51.5" y="25">0</text><text font-family="Arial" font-size="16" font-style="italic" text-anchor="middle" x="61.5" y="20">m</text><text font-family="Arial" font-size="16" font-style="italic" text-anchor="middle" x="72.5" y="20">g</text></svg>
```

it looks like this
[image: image-name.svg]

I am trying to import this into my PDF with the `\includesvg` command from the `svg` package.
The package converts it into the file `image-name_svg-tex.pdf` which looks like below

[image: image-name_svg-tex.pdf]

When rendering my PDF it gives a package `inputenc` error, unicode character not found.
I am guessing because when the `svg` package tries to render this as a simple latex and not math.

How do I get `\includesvg` command to render my math characters?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you post your code as `MWE` ?

Comment: You tagged this question `unicode-math`, but you say you are getting an error from `inputenc`. No TeX engine supports both `inputenc` and `unicode-math`. Could you please post a MWE and say which program you are compiling it in?

Comment: Besides trying to get the svg to work, maybe you can also consider to write the equation in LaTeX directly? `$\ell \sqrt{8\pi\varepsilon_0mg}$` seems a good approximation.

Comment: What's an `MWE`? I used LaTeX directly earlier. But now I have a bunch of SVG files that I need to put into a PDF.

Comment: I am compiling with `pylatex` and the compiler is `pdflatex`. I've also tried `latexmk`. Those are the two options available in `pylatex` @Davislor

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different options, depending on which problem you actually need to solve.

If you aren’t trying to generate the same output, but to include a SVG graphic that your converter does not support, you might convert the SVG to a PDF with embedded fonts, using an external tool (or generate a PDF with `\documentclass{standalone}`). Then, include the PDF with `graphicx` instead of a SVG.  This can embed OpenType fonts into a PDFTeX document, and allows them to be copied and searched.  It is also a good way to insert words or short phrases from a language with a complex script when you’re forced to use legacy tools.

If you can use `unicode-math`, you can write this expression in Arial, or a sans-serif math font, without going through a SVG or MathML.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont{Arial}[range=up]
\setmathfont{Arial Italic}[range=it]
\setmathfont{Arial Bold}[range=bfup]
\setmathfont{Arial Bold Italic}[range=bfit]

\newcommand\epsilonnought{\varepsilon_{\scriptscriptstyle 0}}

\begin{document}
\[ \ell \sqrt{8 \pi \epsilonnought m g }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Arial + Fira Math sample]

(Yes, the subscript 0 is too low in this font.)

If you are using PDFLaTeX, you can use URW Arial as a substitute:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arevmath}
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\newcommand\epsilonnought{\varepsilon_{\scriptscriptstyle 0}}

\begin{document}
\[ \ell \sqrt{8 \pi \epsilonnought m g }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: URW Arial + Arev Math sample]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP is trying to import SVG, not produce an equivalent equation without SVG.

Comment: @HenriMenke The last paragraph does say how to do precisely that. As I stated, there are several possible solutions, depending on which problem the OP is actually trying to solve.

Comment: @HenriMenke I moved that paragraph to the top, so people won’t miss it.